# C++ std::set ordering not working with customer class*

Tags: c++, stl, set

I'm using a set of pointers to a custom abstract class:

```
std::set<Item*>* Stuff;
```

I create two Periodical objects (concrete classes, single inheritance) that store a string and a customer Date object. I then insert both into the set.

```
Date bDate(20140302);
Periodical* B = new Periodical("b", bDate);

Date aDate(20140301);
Periodical* A = new Periodical("a", aDate);

poo->insert(B);
poo->insert(A);
```

Next, I run a couple of lines of code that confirms object A < B and prints the set "in order".

```
if(*A == *B) { std::cout << "*A == *B" << std::endl;}
if(*A < *B) { std::cout << "*A < *B" << std::endl;}
if(*A > *B) { std::cout << "*A > *B" << std::endl;}

//print in order from beginning to end
for (std::set<Item*>::iterator it=poo->begin(); it!=poo->end(); ++it) {

    std::cout << ' ' << **it << std::endl;
}
```

Here is the problem:

```
*A < *B
20140302 b
20140301 a
```

So I think to myself, sure, maybe I'm using pointers and thats why std::less isn't working. Then I try this:

```
std::set<Item*, std::less<Item**>>* Periodicals2 = new std::set<Item*,   std::less<Item**>>();

Date bDate(20140302);
Periodical* B = new Periodical("b", bDate);

Date aDate(20140301);
Periodical* A = new Periodical("a", aDate);

Periodicals2->insert(B);
Periodicals2->insert(A);
```

...and get some horrible STL relegated error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__tree:1596:17: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'value_compare' (aka 'std::__1::less<Item **>')
```

Where am I going wrong??

Comment: `std::less` works fine for pointers. Print the pointers, and not what they point to, and see.

Comment: @ juanchopanza: It looks like its sorting by pointer address. The order the objects were created looks to be how they end up in the set regardless of insert order.
[0] Periodical * 0x100103c50 0x0000000100103c50
[1] Periodical * 0x100103c80 0x0000000100103c80

Comment: Exactly. That is what it is supposed to do. You have a set of pointers, so it sorts the pointers.

Comment: Ok working as expected. Now to figure out why I'm getting the compiler error when I try to set my own comparator.

Comment: Maybe you wanted to compare Items by their contents, but not by pointers ? If so - look at this http://ideone.com/156GS8

Answer (score 1):

Everyone's comments are right on track. Sure, its working all right except I'm sorting pointer addresses instead of what I really want.

Once you pulled me out of the my death spiral, I started looking at defining my own comparator:

```
std::set<Item*, std::less<Item**>>* poo2 = new std::set<Item*, std::less<Item**>>();
```

Unfortunately, that line showed zero syntax errors, but it was throwing this error:

```
1596:17: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'value_compare' (aka 'std::__1::less<Item **>')
```

I figured I was likely making some funky syntax error so I just searched a bit and defined my own compare:

```
struct compare {
    bool operator()(const Item* lhs, const Item* rhs) const {

        return *lhs < *rhs;
    }
};
```

..which gives me just what I expect:

```
 20140301 a
 20140302 b
```

Comment: Hmmm... This is exactly what I gave you in comment :)